# Can't See anything

Tags: rendering, animation

Typically learning by following the common donut tutorial.

have no idea what key(s) I pressed whilst working my own thing, but i switched to rendered view and then back to solid view and nothing is showing, even in wireframe.

managed to get my plate showing and only my plate.

1. i can see everything in other tabs (shading/UV/Sculpting)
   [image: 1.]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: these are clipping border, press Alt B to remove